# using custom database to store session asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, session

A few months ago I asked a question here about accessing a session object using the SessionId in a web service that is being used by an outside application. The suggestion that seemed to work the best was to use SQL Server to store session and query the database by sessionID.

However, because of some restriction of 3rd party products I can only store session InProc. The only way that I figured out is to create my own database that basically simulates the ASPState database. However, the problem is that I have to figure out how to ensure that my custom state database updates everywhere that the ASPsession database would.

My question is, is there any other way for me to be able to return session data from a web service only using the SessionID?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [session state store provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried doing that. However, the 3rd party product, namely the Sitecore CMS, only operates if the SessionState mode is InProc, and nothing else. Are there any other possible work arounds?

Comment: @Matt - sorry, I don't know enough about Sitecore. Did you look through their documentation or contact them?

Comment: I contacted them, and its a known issue. I was just seeing if I can get around it - i.e. getting a session object from sessionID while using InProc session store mode.